# Unable to select the latest record without duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql, database, greatest-n-per-group

I am trying to select the latest record of all the students (I don't want a student's past grade, only their most recent). Currently, its just returning me one result.

**student_grade table**

```
╔════╤═══════╤═══════╤═════════════════════╗
║ id │ name  │ grade │ date_added          ║
╠════╪═══════╪═══════╪═════════════════════╣
║ 1  │ bob   │ 23    │ 2019-10-01 14:25:00 ║
╟────┼───────┼───────┼─────────────────────╢
║ 2  │ james │ 45    │ 2019-10-02 17:31:27 ║
╟────┼───────┼───────┼─────────────────────╢
║ 3  │ mike  │ 42    │ 2019-10-03 18:08:13 ║
╟────┼───────┼───────┼─────────────────────╢
║ 4  │ bob   │ 68    │ 2019-10-04 02:00:00 ║
╟────┼───────┼───────┼─────────────────────╢
║ 5  │ mike  │ 83    │ 2019-10-04 09:28:43 ║
╟────┼───────┼───────┼─────────────────────╢
║ 6  │ bob   │ 23    │ 2019-10-04 11:42:00 ║
╟────┼───────┼───────┼─────────────────────╢
║ 7  │ james │ 86    │ 2019-10-05 12:11:20 ║
╚════╧═══════╧═══════╧═════════════════════╝
```

**What I want it to return**

```
╔════╤═══════╤═══════╤═════════════════════╗
║ id │ name  │ grade │ date_added          ║
╠════╪═══════╪═══════╪═════════════════════╣
║ 5  │ mike  │ 83    │ 2019-10-04 09:28:43 ║
╟────┼───────┼───────┼─────────────────────╢
║ 6  │ bob   │ 23    │ 2019-10-04 11:42:00 ║
╟────┼───────┼───────┼─────────────────────╢
║ 7  │ james │ 86    │ 2019-10-05 12:11:20 ║
╚════╧═══════╧═══════╧═════════════════════╝
```

**My sql statement**

```
SELECT id, DISTINCT name, grade, max(date_added)
FROM student_grade
ORDER BY date_added DESC
```

Or an efficient way of returning me this detail. I'm a little stuck as to how I can get this.

Comment: This is a very common problem. I have added [tag:greatest-n-per-group] tag to the question. You can get a plethora of techniques here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group?tab=Votes

Comment: use this SELECT s_g.id,s_g.name,s_g.grade,s_g.date_added
FROM student_grade s_g
     INNER JOIN (
          SELECT name, max(grade) as maxgrade
          FROM student_grade
          GROUP BY name
    ) s_g1 ON s_g1.name = s_g.name  and s_g1.maxgrade = s_g.grade

Comment: @nbk with this you are rertrieving the row(s) matching the highest grade of each student instead of the latest grade. Thus, for the ```bob``` record you will get id 4 instead of 6

Comment: i know but id seems only to be a autoincrement value without any other purpose, so i don't think that he needs the biggest id instead the highest grade, but this hould be asked before hand

Answer (score 0):

Use a subquery to first select the max id for each name and then the record related to this id :

```
SELECT sg.*
FROM student_grade sg
     INNER JOIN (
          SELECT name, max(id) as id
          FROM student_grade
          GROUP BY name
    ) x ON x.name = sg.name AND x.id = sg.id
```

I assumed that the `id` is the right field to find the last added record. Maybe `date_added` would be more rightful but if they have the same functional meaning, using `id` is more efficient

Comment: This doesn't work.

Comment: what do you mean ? "This doesn't work" is not helpful